# flashing when reloading a list with jquery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a code that loads list items and refreshes every 5 seconds, but there is a flash when it reloads every 5 seconds.

this function will be called every 5 seconds via another function that fetches data from the server.

```
_.each(f, function(e) {
    var m = new MyModel(e);
    var itemView = new App.Views.ListView({ model: m });
    itemView.render();
});
```

from ListView render function

```
s.prototype.render = function () {
    return this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())).appendTo('#files'), this
}
```

I even tried to put all itemView data into an array and at the end `$('#files').html(arraydata)` but still it blinks/flashes.

Comment: What's your `ListView` look like ?